# Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1fd57580, or it may have already been ended

Tags: ios, xcode6

The AppDelegate.m file contains

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskID = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:taskID];
    }];
}
```

I don't know why I have got this message in the gdb

> Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier
>   1fd57580, or it may have already been ended. Break in
>   UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is all wrong. It should be something like this:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskID = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    // Code to ensure your background processing stops executing
    // so it reaches the call to endBackgroundTask:
}];

// Put the code you want executed in the background here

if (taskID != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:taskID];
}
```

Comment: I have seen some answer from the network like these:`[application endBackgroundTask:taskID];
    taskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;`And I found "Value stored to 'taskID' is never read" from Analyze, so taskID = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; is optional？？？

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking in your comment but it reminded my of a small change. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using location updates in the background, add the code below at the time of getting location authorization from the user. That's because Apple changed the default value of `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to `NO` from iOS 9 onwards.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
}
```